# Magento 2: EAV Attribute is not showing on catalog page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, eav, external-script

I've made an EAV attribute using an external script but the attribute is not showing on catalogue page.
The database has created.
I tried to put value in EAV Database but nothing works.

Ext_Script in public folder:

```
<?php 

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');


$EavSetup = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
$eavSetupFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');


$setup = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface'); 
$eavSetup = $eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


$code = 'cat_after_description';
$eavSetup->addAttribute("catalog_category", $code, [
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'Secondary Description',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '',
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'apply_to' => '',
    'group'    => 'Custom Settings',
]);
// public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel
$eav_attribute = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');
$attr = $eav_attribute->loadByCode("catalog_category", $code);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_settings">

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Settings</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">99</item>
            </item>
        </argument>



        <field name="visible_on_home">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Show on home</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>


        <field name="award_winning">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">award winning</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="award_winning_tooltip">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">award winning tooltip</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string">this massage will be show on hover</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>


        <field name="is_new">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">is new</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>


        <field name="homesection">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Model\Home\Section\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">home section</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">flip</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">homesection</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="primary_image" sortOrder="40" formElement="fileUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Primary Image</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="ExampleAdminNewPage/category_thumb/upload"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
<!---->
        <field name="secondary_image" sortOrder="50" formElement="fileUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Secondary Image</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="ExampleAdminNewPage/category_thumb/secondary"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field> -->

        <field name="secondary_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Secondary image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/secondary</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ExampleAdminNewPage/category_thumb/secondary"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="primary_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Primary image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ExampleAdminNewPage/category_thumb/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: custom attribute]

Answer (score 0):

**Create Attribute :-**

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'mp_new_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Mageplaza Attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => 1,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
```

**Display Attribute :-**

> **Create category_form.xml file**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="mp_new_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">new attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```